# Use URL parameter to build IFrame?

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to have an iframe, which displays the page given as parameter in the url.
I'm using ASP.NET MVC4

so I wanna do something like this:

updated it... but still not right i think

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_GET['link']){
 $link = $_GET['link'];}
 ?>

<iframe name="inlineframe" src="<?php $link ?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"          width="500" height="180" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" ></iframe>
```

but i can't figure out the right code for this. can anyone help?

I also tried echoing php, but that doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Try to use the method $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: Agreed with Sergey. However, I do hope you have a good reason to use iframes at all... Because they're pretty terrible.

Comment: yes pretty good reason, im intern and boss is asking for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code snippet is this:

```
src="<?php $link ?>"
```

You're calling the variable, but doing nothing with it

To write the variable in the src attribute, use echo:

```
src="<?php echo $link ?>"
```

You should also remove the ! in your if statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $link = '';
    if(isset($_GET['link']){
        $link = $_GET['link'];
    }
 ?>
```

Also `echo` your link variable.
`src="<?php echo $link; ?>"`

Comment: thanks, i chose the other answer because he responded a little bit faster, but both answers helped :)